# try to print out a matrix NameError: name 'Qb_matrix' is not defined

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, nameerror

I tried to print out a matrix using code as follow, however, it showed up nameerror.
i wonder where specifically should i define the matrix?
can python recognise the abbreviation as Qb to Q_bar?

```
import numpy as np

Q11 = 14.583
Q12 = 1.4583
Q23 = 0
Q22 = 3.646
Q33 = 4.2
theta = 60

def Q_bar(Q11, Q12, Q22, Q33, theta):


n = np.sin(theta*np.pi/180)
m = np.cos(theta*np.pi/180)
Qb_11 = Q11*m**4 + 2*(Q12 + 2*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q22*n**4
Qb_22 = Q11*n**4 + 2*(Q12 + 2*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q22*m**4
Qb_33 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2*Q12 - 2*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q33*(m**4 + n**4)
Qb_12 = (Q11 + Q22 - 4*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q12*(m**4 + n**4)
Qb_13 = (Q11 - Q12 - 2*Q33)*n*m**3 + (Q12 - Q22 + 2*Q33)*n**3*m
Qb_23 = (Q11 - Q12 - 2*Q33)*n**3*m + (Q12 - Q22 + 2*Q33)*n*m**3
Qb_matrix = np.array([[Qb_11, Qb_12, Qb_13],[Qb_12, Qb_22, Qb_23],[Qb_13, Qb_23, Qb_33]])
return(Qb_matrix)

print(Qb_matrix)
```

Comment: You never call your function so the code inside it is never run. Also if you did cal lyour function you would need to catch the return alue as `Qb_matrix` will only exist in the scope of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never call your function so the code inside it is never executed. Further more even if you did call the function. The variable Qb_matrix which you create in the function will only exist inside the function scope, when you return it you need to store that returned value.

```
import numpy as np

Q11 = 14.583
Q12 = 1.4583
Q23 = 0
Q22 = 3.646
Q33 = 4.2
theta = 60

def Q_bar(Q11, Q12, Q22, Q33, theta):
    n = np.sin(theta*np.pi/180)
    m = np.cos(theta*np.pi/180)
    Qb_11 = Q11*m**4 + 2*(Q12 + 2*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q22*n**4
    Qb_22 = Q11*n**4 + 2*(Q12 + 2*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q22*m**4
    Qb_33 = (Q11 + Q22 - 2*Q12 - 2*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q33*(m**4 + n**4)
    Qb_12 = (Q11 + Q22 - 4*Q33)*n**2*m**2 + Q12*(m**4 + n**4)
    Qb_13 = (Q11 - Q12 - 2*Q33)*n*m**3 + (Q12 - Q22 + 2*Q33)*n**3*m
    Qb_23 = (Q11 - Q12 - 2*Q33)*n**3*m + (Q12 - Q22 + 2*Q33)*n*m**3
    Qb_matrix = np.array([[Qb_11, Qb_12, Qb_13],[Qb_12, Qb_22, Qb_23],[Qb_13, Qb_23, Qb_33]])
    return(Qb_matrix)

my_qb_matrix = Q_bar(Q11, Q12, Q22, Q33, theta)
print(my_qb_matrix)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[ 6.659175    1.179375    2.52896738]
 [ 1.179375   12.127675    2.20689254]
 [ 2.52896738  2.20689254  3.921075  ]]
```